# Returning using a shortened if else statement in Python

Tags: python

I was going through ways of shortening a normal `if else` statement.
One of the formats I found was to change this:

```
if x == 1:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Into this:

```
print("Yes") if x == 1 else print("No")
```

Is the code above considered pythonic? Otherwise, what would be a pythonic way of shortening the `if else` statement?

I also tried using `return` instead of `print`. I tried

```
return total if x == 1 else return half
```

which resulted in an unreachable statement for the 2nd `return`. Is there a way of doing it that i'm not able to see?

Finally, I tried to use an `else if` instead of an `else` with the code, but that wouldn't work either.

```
print(total) if x == 1 else print(half) if x == 2
```

The code above probably looks stupid logic-wise. Am I missing out on the proper format, or is it really not possible to do `return` and `else if` with this format?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The form

```
print("Yes") if x == 1 else print("No")
```

is not generally considered Pythonic, since `... if ... else ...` is an expression and you're throwing away the value that the expression produces (always `None`). You can use `print("Yes" if x == 1 else "No")` which is Pythonic since the value of the conditional expression is used as the argument to `print`.

The form

```
return total if x == 1 else return half
```

cannot work since `return` is a statement and must occur at the beginning of a logical line. Instead, use

```
return total if x == 1 else half
```

(which is parsed the same as `return (total if x == 1 else half)`).

The code

```
 print(total) if x == 1 else print(half) if x == 2
```

wouldn't work either - the conditional expression is `... if ... else ...`, i.e. each `if` must be paired with an else that follows it; your second `if` is missing the `else` clause; you could use

```
 print(total) if x == 1 else print(half) if x == 2 else print('something else')
```

Again, this wouldn't be considered very pythonic; but you could use

```
 print(total if x == 1 else half if x == 2 else 'something else')
```

not that it would be much better either.

---

Finally, if you're participating in a code golf

```
print("Yes" if x == 1 else "No")
```

can be shortened to

```
print(('No', 'Yes')[x == 1])
```

by using the fact that `True == 1` and `False == 0` and using these to index a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to use the ternary in the print itself ?

```
print("Yes" if x == 1 else "No")
```

Comment: Yours is much shorter :)

Answer (score 1):

A ternary `if..else` operates on *expressions*. `return` is a statement, not an expression. `print()` is an expression, but note the way you wrote it twice - you're printing regardless; it's just the *expression you want to print* that may vary.

```
print("Yes") if x == 1 else print("No")
```

The above is valid, but you don't need to have two references to the same function:

```
print("Yes" if x == 1 else "No")
```

The following is not valid, as you have multiple statements in there:

```
return total if x == 1 else return half
```

Again, operate on the *expressions* you'd like to work with:

```
return total if x == 1 else half
```

Now, a ternary is just that - ternary. It should have three parts, not four.

```
print(total) if x == 1 else print(half) if x == 2
```

In the above, you have four expressions:

- `print(total)`
- `x == 1`
- `print(half)`
- `x == 2`

That's too many. You can have one of the expressions be, itself, a larger expression, although it does always require an `else` (to be ternary):

```
print(total if x == 1 else half if x == 2 else 'Neither 1 nor 2.')
```

With more parentheses to show grouping:

```
print(total if x == 1 else (half if x == 2 else 'Neither 1 nor 2.'))
```

The expression in the inner parentheses above is an expression with a ternary operator itself, as well as an expression in a larger expression with a ternary operator.